# Использует ли pytorch параметр batch_size для автоматического сигментирования входного тензора при обучении?

Tags: python, pytorch

Например есть какая-то сеть (ее тип не так важен)
Определен входной вектор:

```
inputs = torch.randn(datasize, batch_size, n_features).to(device)
```

и целевой вектор:

```
target = torch.randint(0, 3, (datasize, n_classes)).to(device)
```

Цикл только по эпохам:

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    losses = 0
    outputs = model.forward(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, target)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = F.log_softmax(outputs, dim=2)
    outputs = outputs.transpose(0, 1)  # (time, batch, n_class)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(epoch, loss.data)
```

Pytorch умный и сам сегментирует входной тензор на блоки размерностью в batch_size или же внутри цикла по эпохам нужно делать еще цикл и самому заботится о блоках? Я провел эксперименты: Использовал Keros и Pytorch, если я в Kerose изменяю batch_size время обработки данных меняется (чем меньше размер, тем дольше обработка) в pytorch этого не происходит.

Comment: Об этом надо позаботиться самому. Pytorch не делает это автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо! Т.е. в документации по pytorch имеется ввиду тензоры с размерностями не последнем уровне вложения циклов. Жаль, что этого там не написано в явном виде и даже примеры приводятся без циклического вложения. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Вот вам [классический пример](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py) с использованием batch_size...